# Unable to Download Image behind Proxy Server

Tags: java, image, url, download, proxy

I was trying to Download an image present at this [URL](https://drive.google.com/viewerng/img?id=ACFrOgBARAAw2wXaXhoaL1x-Rxwix8yCdpuGXnVehqIJVpb6H8fMJTJudIXp-NRqV88lq2Veh9bUq9x9Qqr3plJHLSWvNpKh2cTcFAjpq4-KLgGNey1JJmJaMLz30tA=&u=0&w=800&page=0) behind a proxy server. Note that the URL does not end with .jpg or .png . If opened through the browser and the image is visible. But while using the following code i am unable to save/download it.

```
int pageno = 1; 
     System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "10.3.100.207");
     System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8080");
     System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "10.3.100.207");
     System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "8080");
     while(pageno < 50)
     {       
         String fileName = String.format("%d",pageno); 
         URL link = new URL("https://drive.google.com/viewerng/img?id=ACFrOgAJjqc29Qp5SCU7TFHN7pEskq8BQPXHZxaORsnhS5LW1Nl1ypxZTiW0Kylbltw3Z0XkMsACVpvmQWyHef3HdXB-XDXduE1HMXblNAMeZ2N5opRAViKbl8GrAYA=&u=0&w=800&page="+pageno);              
         URLConnection myconn = link.openConnection();
         myconn.setRequestProperty ("User-agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
         InputStream in = myconn.getInputStream();
         ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
         int n = 0;
         while (-1!=(n=in.read(buf)))
         {
            out.write(buf, 0, n);
         }
         out.close();
         in.close();
         byte[] response = out.toByteArray();
         FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
         fos.write(response);
         fos.close();
         System.out.println(pageno);
         pageno++;
     }
     System.out.println("Finished");
```

I get the following error:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://drive.google.com/viewerng/img?id=ACFrOgAJjqc29Qp5SCU7TFHN7pEskq8BQPXHZxaORsnhS5LW1Nl1ypxZTiW0Kylbltw3Z0XkMsACVpvmQWyHef3HdXB-XDXduE1HMXblNAMeZ2N5opRAViKbl8GrAYA=&u=0&w=800&page=1
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1627)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
    at ml.DownloadFile.main(DownloadFile.java:31)
```

Comment: Proxy or not, the URL does not seem to be valid.

Comment: But you can see the image using browser

Comment: `HTTP response code 400` means Bad Request, you are probably missing some request parameters. You can see the image on your browser because you're logged into your account.

Comment: @ysaditya, Ok, maybe you need to authenticate your request? - https://developers.google.com/drive/web/auth/web-server

Comment: so what request parameters are to set @Titus

Comment: or How to authenticate @miku

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to authenticate your request. Google Drive uses OAuth2:

- https://developers.google.com/drive/web/auth/web-server
- https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/
- https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list#try-it

A working example using the [Google Client library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/drive/v2) for downloading a file is provided here:

- https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-java#step_3_set_up_the_sample

Comment: a quick question , can i know where are the files which my browser downloads ?

Comment: @ysaditya, in a current Firefox the Download location can be found under the "General" settings tab.